# Android webview not recognized as a standalone browser

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

When creating an application, I noticed it is not recognized as the variable `navigator.standalone` is not set. I first thought I would fix this bij setting it manually when injecting javascript as below:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("navigator.standalone = true;", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG + "jsinject", s);
            }
        });
    }
});
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, webView), "Android");
```

However this injects too late and some Javascript functions won't fire because it is not recognized as a standalone application. Is there a possibility to set the var before the page finished loading?

Comment: ["_Available on Apple's iOS Safari only_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator#non-standard_properties).

Answer (score 0):

I replaces the function `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` with `onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)` this injects the navigator var before the page is fully loaded